# Exception occurred whilst executing system call JMeter OS Sampler error

Tags: jmeter

I need to execute the jmx file from OS process sampler. I am getting the error

> Response code: 500 Response message: Exception occurred whilst
>   executing system call: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jmeter
>   -n -t  C:\test\jmeter\reliability\scripts\test.jmx" (in directory "C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot
>   find the file specified

Here is my values in the OS process sampler.

```
Command: jmeter -n -t  C:\test\jmeter\reliability\scripts\test.jmx


Working directory: C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

You better use  [Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) to run additional jmx

> The include controller is designed to use an external JMX file. To use it, create a Test Fragment underneath the Test Plan and add any desired samplers, controllers etc. below it.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is a little bit wrong.

Whatever you provide into `Command` input field **will be treated as a single command or filename**, it won't be split into [`jmeter.bat`](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/master/bin/jmeter.bat) file with parameters as it's something done by the [`cmd.exe` interpreter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe)

So you need to amend your [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/) configuration as follows:

- Command: `cmd.exe`
- Working directory: `C:\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin`
- First argument: `/c`
- Second argument: `jmeter.bat -n -t  C:\test\jmeter\reliability\scripts\test.jmx`

[image]

Also be aware that according to JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.1.1](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-1-1-released-td5728320.html) or whatever is the latest stable version available at [JMeter downloads page](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) on next available opportunity.